# Как указать папку при клонировании git

Tags: git, git-clone

когда я клонирую git-репозиторий, например

```
git@github.com:mainRepo/index.git
```

то у меня создается папка **index**, где лежат все файлы.

Вопрос: а если я не хочу, что бы создавалась папка **index**, а файлы клонировались просто в ту папку, где я нахожусь, или другую указанную, это возможно?

Comment: git clone url **directory**

Comment: спасибо, то что надо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> в ту папку, где я нахожусь

```
$ git clone url .
```

> другую указанную

```
$ git clone url другой/каталог
```

---

указанный каталог (если уже существует) должен быть пустым. иначе получите ошибку:

> fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.

---

подробности об использовании команды `git clone` смотрите в [документации](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).